# On Windows 10, why does opening a file path written with forward slashes, and containing a space, fail?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I create a folder called "x y" under C:.  There is a space in the name of the folder. In a cmd shell on Windows 10, this command

`start winword.exe "c:/x y/temp.docx"`

fails with the following error:

[Word Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLSJC.png)

If I change the first / to \, it succeeds:

`start winword.exe "c:\x y/temp.docx"`

If I rename the folder to remove the space, and use / again, it succeeds:

`start winword.exe "c:/xy/temp.docx"`

This hurts me, because I use emacs org mode, and org "helpfully" alters all \ in a link path to /.  So my links to files in folders with spaces in their names do not work.

Is this known behaviour?

Comment: What Word does with its command line arguments is entirely up to Word.

Comment: Why on earth would someone write a Win command with forward slashes in the first place? Windows is the only OS I know of that uses the letter "C:\" nomenclature for its drive 'names'. It is also the only OS I know that invariably uses backslashes for paths. if you're running emacs on Win, check if it has a "please don't break my paths" pref somewhere.

Comment: @DanielB I think you are right, it is Word.  In fact if I try this with the 'type' command it only works if the **last** separator in the path is a backslash.  Each utility is doing its own thing.  I naively thought that all apps would be calling the same open API function which would treat slashes and backslashes uniformly.